# Trouble understanding the general polynomial of degree $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field

Herstein defines the general polynomial of degree $n$ over a field $F$ as the polynomial $p(x) = x^n + a_1x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n \in F(a_1, \cdots, a_n)[x]$. From here, since it was previously shown that the group of automorphisms of this field is $S_n$, we show that polynomial is not solvable by radicals over $F$.

But this whole result doesn't make much sense to me. Before, we treated of $F(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ where these "$x_i$" were just symbols, like the "$x$" in a polynomial $p(x)$. And now, we are taking the *coefficients* of $p(x)$, which can very well be inside the field $F$.

For example, the polynomial $x^5 - 7x + 2$ is in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, and so $\mathbb{Q}(a_1, \cdots, a_5) = \mathbb{Q}$, and this seems to contradict the earlier result that the group was $S_5$.

I know I am making a huge mess, but I just can't seem to really grasp the concept, and would love some sort of enlightenment. Since I am self studying, I don't really have a professor to go to.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: We have $(a_1,\ldots ,a_5)=(1,0,0,0,-7,2)$, and of course all these numbers are in $\Bbb Q$? Where is the problem?

Comment: There are 6 numbers.

Comment: Here, what the theorem “on the formal field” $F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ says is that there is no “formal formula” working in the “formal field” that gives all the roots of $p(x)$. What exactly is a formal formula is the usual definition of Galois theory – a tower of field extensions of $F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ starting with enough cyclotomy and then only Kummer extensions, ie rational expressions in the symbols of $F$, roots of unity, the $a_i$, and symbols $b_i$ where $b_i^{n_i}$ is itself a rational function of roots of unity, elements of $F$, the $a_t$ snd the $b_j$, $j < i$. (Cont’d)

Comment: If you think about it, it means just about the definition you would come up with for the sentence “this general polynomial of degree $n$ isn’t solvable with radicals”. What the theorem doesn’t exclude is the existence, for *some* polynomials with coefficients in $F$ (and depending on $F$, it could be *any* polynomial), of “special recipes” that would work well for this particular polynomial.

Comment: After reading and pondering about your comments, I think I've managed to clear it up in my head. I will proceed to write an answer to my own question, and would very much love if you could see whether it is indeed correct!

Comment: @Mindlack I am aware of the existence of "particularly nice" polynomials of higher degree, but why doesn't this violate the theorem that the automorphism group of $F(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ over the elementary symmetric functions in those variables is isomorphic to $S_n$? (Since we can take $x_1$ through $x_n$ to be the roots of the polynomial)

Answer (score 1):

My mistake above was to think I had calculated the *splitting field* of $p(x)$, when, in reality I had calculated the *field over which we are working on*. Let me elaborate.

We want to get to the splitting field $F(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$, where these are the roots of a polynomial. What we have to **start with** are, by the Newton-Girard identities, **the elementary symmetric functions on these roots**, namely, the coefficients of the polynomial $p(x)$, and their generated field, $F(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$.

Dietrich Burde was right in his comment - nothing was wrong, except my interpretation of the problem. When I said $\mathbb{Q}(a_1, \cdots, a_5) = \mathbb{Q}$ in the example, I was absolutely right. The thing is, this "collapsed" field (by which I mean, the result after plugging in the actual particular values) is the particular field of elementary symmetric functions over the roots of this polynomial, which remain unknown. So I didn't obtain $F(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$, as I thought I had, but rather $F(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$.

And the theorem I stated in the question says that $\operatorname{o}(\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(x_1, \cdots, x_5)) = 5!$, whereas, by my original reasoning, I thought I had $\operatorname{o}(\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}) = 1 \neq 5!$ as it should be.

EDIT: I believe the same reasoning explains the apparent contradiction that there are indeed quintics solvable by radicals: when actually plugging in the values of the roots into the field $F(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$, some of them may have already been in the previous field, so the underlying result is much more complex than the theorem on rational functions predicted and the bound may end up being much smaller than $n!$